# Trying to get specif result from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set looked like the below:

```
ID  Pass    DESCRIPTION DATE    STATUS
123 3455    RUNNING 13/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    RUNNING 14/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    RUNNING 15/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    RUNNING 16/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    RUNNING 17/09/2017  DELETED
123 3455    JUMPING 17/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    JUMPING 17/09/2017  DELETED
456 8968    JUMPING 18/09/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 18/09/2017  DELETED
456 8968    JUMPING 06/10/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 07/10/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 08/10/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 09/10/2017  RETIRADO
```

What I'd like to have from this result set would be:

```
ID  Pass    DESCRIPTION DATE    STATUS
123 3455    RUNNING 13/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    RUNNING 17/09/2017  DELETED
123 3455    JUMPING 17/09/2017  INSERTED
123 3455    JUMPING 17/09/2017  DELETED
456 8968    JUMPING 18/09/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 18/09/2017  DELETED
456 8968    JUMPING 06/10/2017  INSERTED
456 8968    JUMPING 09/10/2017  RETIRADO
```

The min and max date of these events, ignoring all dates inside min and max.
ID, Pass and DESCRIPTION can be the same, but when the STATUS change, I'd like to have the min and max results. Could somebody help me?

Comment: which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: How to order the records ? Does `ID/Pass/DESCRIPTION` columns has any impact in finding the min/max date ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Pass,Description,Status ORDER BY Date ASC),
        *
        FROM T1
)
SELECT
  *
  FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Check The [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96d6f/2) Here

Comment: Seems that you need dense_rank instead of row_number. And there must two of them

Comment: Did you check the expected result ? This is nowhere close

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result set in question using `lag`.

```
select * 
from (select t.*,lag(status) over(partition by id order by date_column) as prev_status
      from tbl t
     ) t
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
```

Edit: As there are multiple rows for a given date, you should specify a column for reliable ordering of rows. 
Use `lag(status) over(partition by id order by date_column,other_order_column)` to get consistent results.